# Is there any tool for silverlight3 ui test?

Tags: silverlight, testing, user-interface

I just want to know is there any tool works with silverlight3 for UI testing.I know the Coded UI Test,but it doesn't support silverlight3.

Thanks！

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [SilverlightSpy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/download-silverlight-spy) - get from [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4d50ee31-6426-4968-b00f-bd50ba54d74f)

**For UI Automation Testing:**

The [UI Spy tool](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms727247.aspx) enables developers and testers to view and interact with the user interface (UI) elements of an application. By viewing the application's UI hierarchical structure, property values, and raised events, developers and testers can verify that the UI they are creating is programmatically accessible to assistive technology devices such as screen readers.

I hope this will help you.

More Details: [UI Automation in Silverlight](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2008/02/18/where-is-uispy-exe.aspx)

Comment: I am pretty sure he meant *automated testing* when he said UI test (and mentioned Coded UI Test... which is an automated test tool).

Comment: @HiTechMagic You are right,I mean automated testing.BTW, the "SilverlightSpy" requires Silverlight4 or higher,but I need to work with silverlight3.